# HTML Email - Issues with sending to Outlook

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-email

Apologies for the super generic title, as I couldn't find a proper one for the questions I have.

In my company, we are now investigating the communications we have with our own employees. I've done a small test send with an HTML email (we are using SFMC) to a super small group, and I've seen a couple of minor issues. Since everyone in my company (I'm talking about +5000 employees) uses Outlook, all the issues I'm going to mention are Outlook specific:

1- Some of the emails ended up in the 'Other' instead of the 'Focused'. I don't know the pattern here, why some ended up in one while the rest ended up in the other. I'd like all of them to end up in 'Focused'.

2- People have to press 'Download Images' or 'add the sender to the safe list' or something like that, in order to see the whole HTML email.

How do you think we can overcome those issues? We have never investigated those in our B2C communications as the people who use Outlook in our Consumer audience was very low; but if we can solve this for the internal communications, it can also help with our B2C audience.

I've seen in some newsletters from other companies where they mention 'add our domain to the safe sender list in order to see the messages properly'; but I'd rather not have that; and fix it internally.

One option I'm thinking about is, maybe I can get in touch with our IT department, and see if they can do something about the issue I've mentioned in #2.

What do you think?

Comment: if the person who downvoted can explain why, I can fix / update it.

Comment: By default, Outlook hides images for security reasons. I’m not sure how to change that policy company-wide.

Comment: I know that, but I was assuming since I may have the chance to 'control' the domains by contacting the IT department, maybe, just maybe, there's a way to find a workaround

Comment: For #2, you can try into looking your IT implementing a safe user group. https://serverfault.com/questions/775822/allow-outlook-to-display-download-images-from-approved-domains
I don't have an answer for #1 unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

For #2, you need to embed images as attachments instead of providing external links.

Comment: Is #2 not outlook auto-blocking images from unknown senders?

Comment: If you embed the images, there is nothing to block, known senders or not.

Comment: We're sending the email out from SFMC, and we're going to use HTML emails. How exactly can I reference attached images in an HTML? Plus, we haven't purchased the functionality of having attachments in emails, so even if it's possible to do that, I can't implement it. But I'm still quite interested in how this is done.

Comment: Your HTML body must reference the images using the cid attribute: `<img src="cid:xyz">`. The image attachment must have Content-id MIME header with the matching value (xyz).